# Primary Name Server Not Listed At Parent

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dns-zone, amazon-route53, dns-hosting

I have a hosted zone created in Route53 and updated the NS records under the namespaces of the purchased domain.

Unfortunately the DNS check does not return or point to the new NS records instead gets resolved to old/ previously existing records.

I waited more than 72 hours and still i get "This site can’t be reached"failing with error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in the browser.

Below is a screenshot from the DNS check provided by https://mxtoolbox.com/,

[image]

It shows that the old NS records (First 4 rows with TTL to 48 hours) are present in the Parent and not in local whereas the newly updated records (The last 4 records) are present in the parent and not in the local.

Ping to the domain fails with Unknown host.

Request you to kindly suggest me with the next steps.

Comment: Contact your domain registrar.

Comment: I removed the old name space records which was present under the domain and updated with the new one in the Route 53. Can you please suggest when will the old NS records will be removed completely or any way to force remove it when i do a DNS check?

Comment: What’s the actual domain name? Can’t help without knowing it.

Comment: 1) You are not giving the name concerned and as such your question is mostly offtopic here 2) "I waited more than 72 hours" You don't need to wait when changing authoritative nameservers to double check they were changed properly, there is no "propagation" in the DNS contrary to what you can read everywhere. 3) Use DNSViz or Zonemaster to assess the situation they will clearly show you any error you may have specially since no one else can test for you without the name 4) ping is almost always the wrong tool to troubleshoot, specially for DNS 5) there is no "primary" consideration here

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - NS/SOA records are often cached and they have a TTL. Do you have a reference to the contrary for "there is no "propagation" in the DNS contrary to what you can read everywhere"?

Comment: @JohnHanley "NS/SOA records are often cached and they have a TTL" Yes, and? Primary/secondary is only a distinction that may (and not in all cases) be relevant for the manager of the nameservers it has no working consequences for users of the nameservers. As for propagation, I am not sure what you are asking for? It is for people claiming that the DNS has a propagation to show some proofs, not for others to prove the contrary. But to help it can easily be seen and proved that the DNS is not top down but bottom up: updates do not "flow" downwards, updates are acquired through new queries.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I am not trying to argue or upset you. I understand DNS very well. I was on the AT&T team that wrote one of the first DNS servers and participated in several RFCs. I am just asking for a reference for your comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley If you participated in several RFCs, please let me know which ones related to DNS speak about "propagation". Otherwise you are asking me to prove the negative of something, why it is not instead those thinking that there is "propagation" in the DNS that should prove it exists? And no, the fact that this propagation myth is spread all over (most of the time by people not understanding first the difference between authoritative and recursive nameservers, nor understanding how TTL works) is not a proof it exists. Besides that I do not think there is anymore to discuss here.

Comment: Please share your domain name, without it we can't help. With regards to comments above, my understanding is DNS has caching rather than propagation as it's pulled through a hierarchy of servers which can each cache a reply rather than pushed.

Comment: "DNS propagation" is a commonly used and inaccurate term for the process of DNS cache expiration and how that impacts when a DNS change seems to take effect. I have seen (and mopped up after) several flame wars over the term. We don't need to do it here. Again.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66519744/476716